# Как заменить иконкой FontAwesome input?

Tags: css, css3, html5

Всем привет! Код HTML:

```html
<button onclick="selectAll(this)" id="select_btn"> Select All</button> 
<form method="post" action="block.php">
  <div class="inputs">
    <button type="submit" name="block_user"><i class="fas fa-lock"></i></button> 
    <input type="submit" value="Unblock" name="unblock_user">
    <input type="button" value="LogOut" onClick='location.href="login.php"'>
  </div>  
  <div class="table">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Date of registration</th>
        <th>Last login</th>
        <th>Status</th>
      </tr>        
    </table>
  </div>
</form>
```

В кнопке block_user иконка фонтасома, но кнопка не сабмититься, то есть не отправляет данные.Если вместо button впишу input,кнопка не будет видна.
Как это можно исправить? Чтобы и кнопка сабмитилась, и иконка была видна.
Зараннее спасибо!

Comment: Конкретно в приложенном фрагменте все прекрасно отправляется. Может проблема в javascript, которого мы не видим?

Comment: Javascript-а нет, есть только скрипт, позволяющий выделять все чекбоксы одновременно

Comment: Ваш фрагмент прекрасно работает. При нажатии на кнопку block_user форма отправляется в block.php. Если нет, значит вы привели не достаточно данных для воспроизведения проблемы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем коде в форме 2 сабмита. Возможно первому не хватает value.

```
<button type="submit" name="block_user" value='Block'><i class="fas fa-lock"></i></button>
```